# Using a matrix of data inside a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, mat-file

I need to know how to extract an arbitrary entry of a matrix inside a function. Say a function `f` gets two extra input arguments `i` and `j` to extract element `a(i,j)` of a fixed real-valued matrix. The matrix is in the workspace, and is of large size. The function `f` is inside a long iterative algorithm. Having the whole matrix `a` recalled in each iteration will reduce the speed significantly. This matrix needs either to be defined as a function (so that it can be recalled inside a function), or to be loaded from a **mat-file**. The first option seems to be more efficient, but have no idea how to save a matrix as function.

Comment: It would be nice to see some (minimal) code, or at least pseudocode, that shows how you're calling this function and why you need to access the array through a separate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your question.

Suppose you have array `arr`.  You can do `arr(i,j)` to access elements of it.

Suppose you also have a function `func(arr, i, j)` in the body of the function you can easily access `arr(i,j)` with the parameters.

If `func` returns an array, then you can do `var = func(arr); var(i,j)`

If you want a matrix of functions, make handles to them and store that in an array;

```
a = @func_a;
b = @func_b;
c = @func_c;
funcarray = [a b c];
```

Comment: The array we are talking about is pre-specified and is of large size. I am looking for a way to create a function such as `arr(i,j)` out of sheets of data.

Comment: @SaraWinslet Ordinarily, you pass the array to the function. Since MATLAB uses copy on write, the array will not be copied in the function unless you change the data in it (assuming that memory is your concern). If you already know the array and the index that you're interested in, why not just pass `a(i,j)` to the function instead? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I will be using all of the entries. The function itself is inside a long iterative algorithm.

Comment: @SaraWinslet what is at `arr(i,j)` - is it a number?  A string?  Arrays typically do not contain functions.  If it is a number and you want to just operate on that element of an array, then beaker is correct -- why not just pass `arr(i,j)`?

Comment: @SaraWinslet Can you edit your question to include an example of your program logic? I don't think I understand what you're asking and why you need a function to access an array.

Comment: @SaraWinslet I saw your edit -- are you saying that passing `arr` to the `f` and indexing inside of `f` will be slow?  If so, have you profiled it and confirmed that to be the case?  If you don't alter the array in `f`, only grab from an index of it, matlab shouldn't copy anything and it should be very fast.